# Convert 1D python list consisting of 2D lists to 3D list for Keras

Tags: python, arrays, list, machine-learning, keras

I wonder how to efficiently convert a python list of (3000,) containing 2D lists of (3, x) with x being a variable length, to a 3D list or numpy array of (3000, 3, x) that can be used as input for Keras LSTM.

What I have: list - (3000,) with each (3,x) 
What I need: list - (3000, 3, x)

Thank you!

Comment: A list of 3000 elements containing 2D lists of shape (3, x) is already a 3D list of shape (3000, 3, x). However, you need to convert it to a numpy array before feeding it to a keras input.

Comment: @nonlinear yes, but the arr.shape will still give me (3000,) and not (3000, 3, x) thus Keras will complain :(

Comment: Can you provide a [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?